# Motion exiting without any error (USB web camera)

Tags: raspicam, webcam, motion

I am trying to use Raspberry pi as a web camera streaming server. I am following this [tutorial](https://tutorials-raspberrypi.com/raspberry-pi-security-camera-livestream-setup/) which uses [Motion tool](https://github.com/Motion-Project/motion).

When I start the motion service, it exists without giving me an error and when I go to the streaming URL(http://myrpi:8081) I get nothing there.

**I tried to take a few pictures using FFmpeg and it worked.**

`ffmpeg -f video4linux2 -i /dev/video0 -vframes 2 test%3d.jpeg`

**This means my USB Web camera is working** with the raspberry pi. I am attaching configuration and log file contents below. Please let me know if you need more details.

-- **Thank you in advance**.

- **Model Number**: Raspberry Pi 4 Model B Rev 1.4
- **OS Version**: Raspbian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)
- **USB Web Camera Model**: Please see below:

```
$ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 1e4e:0100 Cubeternet WebCam

$ v4l2-ctl --device=/dev/video0 --all
Driver Info:
    Driver name      : uvcvideo
    Card type        : USB2.0 Camera: USB2.0 Camera
    Bus info         : usb-0000:01:00.0-1.3
    Driver version   : 5.10.63
    Capabilities     : 0x84a00001
        Video Capture
        Metadata Capture
        Streaming
        Extended Pix Format
        Device Capabilities
    Device Caps      : 0x04200001
        Video Capture
        Streaming
        Extended Pix Format
Media Driver Info:
    Driver name      : uvcvideo
    Model            : USB2.0 Camera: USB2.0 Camera
    Serial           : 
    Bus info         : usb-0000:01:00.0-1.3
    Media version    : 5.10.63
    Hardware revision: 0x00000002 (2)
    Driver version   : 5.10.63
Interface Info:
    ID               : 0x03000002
    Type             : V4L Video
Entity Info:
    ID               : 0x00000001 (1)
    Name             : USB2.0 Camera: USB2.0 Camera
    Function         : V4L2 I/O
    Flags         : default
    Pad 0x01000007   : 0: Sink
      Link 0x02000010: from remote pad 0x100000a of entity 'Extension 4': Data, Enabled, Immutable
Priority: 2
Video input : 0 (Camera 1: ok)
Format Video Capture:
    Width/Height      : 640/480
    Pixel Format      : 'YUYV' (YUYV 4:2:2)
    Field             : None
    Bytes per Line    : 1280
    Size Image        : 614400
    Colorspace        : sRGB
    Transfer Function : Rec. 709
    YCbCr/HSV Encoding: ITU-R 601
    Quantization      : Default (maps to Limited Range)
    Flags             : 
Crop Capability Video Capture:
    Bounds      : Left 0, Top 0, Width 640, Height 480
    Default     : Left 0, Top 0, Width 640, Height 480
    Pixel Aspect: 1/1
Selection Video Capture: crop_default, Left 0, Top 0, Width 640, Height 480, Flags: 
Selection Video Capture: crop_bounds, Left 0, Top 0, Width 640, Height 480, Flags: 
Streaming Parameters Video Capture:
    Capabilities     : timeperframe
    Frames per second: 30.000 (30/1)
    Read buffers     : 0
                     brightness 0x00980900 (int)    : min=-127 max=127 step=1 default=0 value=0
                       contrast 0x00980901 (int)    : min=0 max=127 step=1 default=62 value=62
                     saturation 0x00980902 (int)    : min=0 max=255 step=1 default=64 value=64
                            hue 0x00980903 (int)    : min=-16000 max=16000 step=1 default=20 value=20
                          gamma 0x00980910 (int)    : min=16 max=500 step=1 default=125 value=125
                      sharpness 0x0098091b (int)    : min=0 max=31 step=1 default=2 value=2
```

- **Conf file motion.conf**: Please see below

```
# Rename this distribution example file to motion.conf
#
# This config file was generated by motion 4.3.2
# Documentation:  /usr/share/doc/motion/motion_guide.html
#
# This file contains only the basic configuration options to get a
# system working.  There are many more options available.  Please
# consult the documentation for the complete list of all options.
#

############################################################
# System control configuration parameters
############################################################

# Start in daemon (background) mode and release terminal.
daemon on

# Start in Setup-Mode, daemon disabled.
setup_mode off

# File to store the process ID.
; pid_file value

# File to write logs messages into.  If not defined stderr and syslog is used.
log_file /var/log/motion/motion.log

# Level of log messages [1..9] (EMG, ALR, CRT, ERR, WRN, NTC, INF, DBG, ALL).
log_level 6

# Target directory for pictures, snapshots and movies
# target_dir /var/lib/motion: this was default setting
target_dir /home/pi/Monitor

# Video device (e.g. /dev/video0) to be used for capturing.
videodevice /dev/video0
# videodevice /dev/video1
# Parameters to control video device.  See motion_guide.html
; vid_control_params value

# The full URL of the network camera stream.
; netcam_url value

# Name of mmal camera (e.g. vc.ril.camera for pi camera).
; mmalcam_name value

# Camera control parameters (see raspivid/raspistill tool documentation)
; mmalcam_control_params value

############################################################
# Image Processing configuration parameters
############################################################

# Image width in pixels.
width 640

# Image height in pixels.
height 480

# Maximum number of frames to be captured per second.
framerate 15

# Text to be overlayed in the lower left corner of images
text_left CAMERA1

# Text to be overlayed in the lower right corner of images.
text_right %Y-%m-%d\n%T-%q

############################################################
# Motion detection configuration parameters
############################################################

# Always save pictures and movies even if there was no motion.
emulate_motion off

# Threshold for number of changed pixels that triggers motion.
threshold 1500

# Noise threshold for the motion detection.
; noise_level 32

# Despeckle the image using (E/e)rode or (D/d)ilate or (l)abel.
despeckle_filter EedDl

# Number of images that must contain motion to trigger an event.
minimum_motion_frames 1

# Gap in seconds of no motion detected that triggers the end of an event.
event_gap 60

# The number of pre-captured (buffered) pictures from before motion.
pre_capture 3

# Number of frames to capture after motion is no longer detected.
post_capture 0

############################################################
# Script execution configuration parameters
############################################################

# Command to be executed when an event starts.
; on_event_start value

# Command to be executed when an event ends.
; on_event_end value

# Command to be executed when a movie file is closed.
; on_movie_end value

############################################################
# Picture output configuration parameters
############################################################

# Output pictures when motion is detected
picture_output off

# File name(without extension) for pictures relative to target directory
picture_filename %Y%m%d%H%M%S-%q

############################################################
# Movie output configuration parameters
############################################################

# Create movies of motion events.
movie_output on

# Maximum length of movie in seconds.
movie_max_time 60

# The encoding quality of the movie. (0=use bitrate. 1=worst quality, 100=best)
movie_quality 45

# Container/Codec to used for the movie. See motion_guide.html
movie_codec mkv

# File name(without extension) for movies relative to target directory
movie_filename %t-%v-%Y%m%d%H%M%S

############################################################
# Webcontrol configuration parameters
############################################################

# Port number used for the webcontrol.
webcontrol_port 8080

# Restrict webcontrol connections to the localhost.
webcontrol_localhost on

# Type of configuration options to allow via the webcontrol.
webcontrol_parms 0

############################################################
# Live stream configuration parameters
############################################################

# The port number for the live stream.
stream_port 8081

# Restrict stream connections to the localhost.
stream_localhost off

##############################################################
# Camera config files - One for each camera.
##############################################################
; camera /usr/etc/motion/camera1.conf
; camera /usr/etc/motion/camera2.conf
; camera /usr/etc/motion/camera3.conf
; camera /usr/etc/motion/camera4.conf

##############################################################
# Directory to read '.conf' files for cameras.
##############################################################
; camera_dir /usr/etc/motion/conf.d
```

- **Log file content**(/var/log/motion/motion.log): Please see below:

```
[0:motion] [NTC] [ALL] [Dec 04 17:03:18] motion_startup: Motion 4.3.2 Started
[0:motion] [NTC] [ALL] [Dec 04 17:03:18] motion_startup: Using default log type (ALL)
[0:motion] [NTC] [ALL] [Dec 04 17:03:18] motion_startup: Using log type (ALL) log level (NTC)
[0:motion] [NTC] [ALL] [Dec 04 17:03:18] become_daemon: Motion going to daemon mode
[0:motion] [NTC] [ALL] [Dec 04 17:03:18] motion_startup: Motion running as daemon process
[0:motion] [NTC] [STR] [Dec 04 17:03:18] webu_start_strm: Starting all camera streams on port 8081
[0:motion] [NTC] [STR] [Dec 04 17:03:18] webu_strm_ntc: Started camera 0 stream on port 8081
[0:motion] [NTC] [STR] [Dec 04 17:03:18] webu_start_ctrl: Starting webcontrol on port 8080
[0:motion] [NTC] [STR] [Dec 04 17:03:18] webu_start_ctrl: Started webcontrol on port 8080
[0:motion] [NTC] [ENC] [Dec 04 17:03:18] ffmpeg_global_init: ffmpeg libavcodec version 58.91.100 libavformat version 58.45.100
[0:motion] [NTC] [ALL] [Dec 04 17:03:18] translate_init: Language: English
[0:motion] [NTC] [ALL] [Dec 04 17:03:18] motion_start_thread: Camera ID: 0 is from /etc/motion/motion.conf
[0:motion] [NTC] [ALL] [Dec 04 17:03:18] motion_start_thread: Camera ID: 0 Camera Name: (null) Device: /dev/video0
[0:motion] [NTC] [ALL] [Dec 04 17:03:18] main: Waiting for threads to finish, pid: 4956
[1:ml1] [NTC] [ALL] [Dec 04 17:03:18] motion_init: Camera 0 started: motion detection Enabled
[1:ml1] [NTC] [VID] [Dec 04 17:03:18] vid_start: Opening V4L2 device
[1:ml1] [NTC] [VID] [Dec 04 17:03:18] v4l2_device_open: Using videodevice /dev/video0 and input -1
[1:ml1] [NTC] [VID] [Dec 04 17:03:18] v4l2_device_capability: - VIDEO_CAPTURE
[1:ml1] [NTC] [VID] [Dec 04 17:03:18] v4l2_device_capability: - STREAMING
[1:ml1] [NTC] [VID] [Dec 04 17:03:18] v4l2_input_select: Name = "Camera 1"- CAMERA
[1:ml1] [NTC] [VID] [Dec 04 17:03:18] v4l2_norm_select: Device does not support specifying PAL/NTSC norm
[1:ml1] [NTC] [VID] [Dec 04 17:03:18] v4l2_pixfmt_select: Configuration palette index 17 (YU12) for 640x480 doesn't work.
[1:ml1] [NTC] [VID] [Dec 04 17:03:18] v4l2_pixfmt_select: Supported palettes:
[1:ml1] [NTC] [VID] [Dec 04 17:03:18] v4l2_pixfmt_select: (0) YUYV (YUYV 4:2:2)
[1:ml1] [NTC] [VID] [Dec 04 17:03:18] v4l2_pixfmt_set: Testing palette YUYV (640x480)
[1:ml1] [NTC] [VID] [Dec 04 17:03:18] v4l2_pixfmt_set: Using palette YUYV (640x480)
[1:ml1] [NTC] [VID] [Dec 04 17:03:18] v4l2_pixfmt_select: Selected palette YUYV
[1:ml1] [NTC] [ALL] [Dec 04 17:03:18] image_ring_resize: Resizing pre_capture buffer to 1 items
[1:ml1] [NTC] [ALL] [Dec 04 17:03:18] image_ring_resize: Resizing pre_capture buffer to 4 items
[1:ml1] [NTC] [ALL] [Dec 04 17:03:18] mlp_actions: End of event 1
[1:ml1] [NTC] [ALL] [Dec 04 17:03:18] motion_loop: Thread exiting
[1:ml1] [NTC] [VID] [Dec 04 17:03:18] vid_close: Cleaning up V4L2 device
[1:ml1] [NTC] [VID] [Dec 04 17:03:18] v4l2_cleanup: Closing video device /dev/video0
[0:motion] [NTC] [ALL] [Dec 04 17:03:19] main: Threads finished
[0:motion] [NTC] [ALL] [Dec 04 17:03:19] main: Motion terminating
[0:motion] [NTC] [ALL] [Dec 04 17:03:19] motion_remove_pid: Closing logfile (/var/log/motion/motion.log).
```

- **Motion service status**: Please see below

```
$ sudo service motion status

● motion.service - Motion detection video capture daemon
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/motion.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: inactive (dead) since Sat 2021-12-04 17:03:19 IST; 46s ago
       Docs: man:motion(1)
    Process: 4955 ExecStart=/usr/bin/motion (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 4955 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
        CPU: 346ms

Dec 04 17:03:17 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started Motion detection video capture daemon.
Dec 04 17:03:18 raspberrypi motion[4955]: [0:motion] [NTC] [ALL] conf_load: Processing thread 0 - config file /etc/motion/motion.conf
Dec 04 17:03:18 raspberrypi motion[4955]: [0:motion] [NTC] [ALL] conf_load: Processing thread 0 - config file /etc/motion/motion.conf
Dec 04 17:03:18 raspberrypi motion[4955]: [0:motion] [NTC] [ALL] motion_startup: Logging to file (/var/log/motion/motion.log)
Dec 04 17:03:18 raspberrypi motion[4955]: [0:motion] [NTC] [ALL] motion_startup: Logging to file (/var/log/motion/motion.log)
Dec 04 17:03:19 raspberrypi systemd[1]: motion.service: Succeeded.
```

Comment: any updates? I've run into the same issue running a RPI with RPI camera: Motion just terminates and fails to do any processing. Thanks

Comment: Hi. I'm having a [similar issue](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/136349/motion-terminating-immediately) with the RPi cam. Were you able to fix it?

Comment: Unfortunately no. @ThomasWeller

Comment: See here: https://github.com/Motion-Project/motion/pull/303
tl;dr: you shouldn't set "daemon on" if you run it as simple frpm systemd